# Handle error in Spring Webflux MultipartFile.transferTo

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using spring-webflux and I wonder if someone knows how to handle error in `Mono<Void>`. I'm using `MultipartFile`'s method `transferTo`, which on success returns `Mono.empty()` and in other cases it wraps exceptions in `Mono.error()`.

```
public Mono<UploadedFile> create(final User user, final FilePart file) {
    final UploadedFile uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(file.filename(), user.getId());
    final Path path = Paths.get(fileUploadConfig.getPath(), uploadedFile.getId());

    file.transferTo(path);

    uploadedFile.setFilePath(path.toString());
    return repo.save(uploadedFile);
}
```

I want to save `UploadedFile` only in case `transferTo` ended successfully. But I can't use map/flatMap because empty Mono obviously doesn't emit value. `onErrorResume` only accepts `Mono` with same type (`Void`).

Comment: `transferTo` is blocking - you probably want to use an `AsnychronousFileChannel` instead as in [this example](https://github.com/entzik/reactive-spring-boot-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thekirschners/springbootsamples/reactiveupload/ReactiveUploadResource.java) it is, unfortunately, more complicated than a simple method call.

Comment: @MichaelBerry thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to chain your operators like this:

```
    ...
    return Mono.just(file)
        .map(f -> f.transferTo(path))
        .then(Mono.just(uploadedFile))
        .flatMap(uF -> {
            uF.setFilePath(path.toString());
            return repo.save(uF)
        });
}
```

if your *transferTo* will finished successfully it calls *then* operators.

P.S. if I'm not mistaken **FilePart** is blocking, try to avoid it.

Comment: Yay! I knew that I must have overlooked something. Thank you!